# If $f$ is continuous and $\int_0^1 f(x) x^n dx = 0$ for all $n \ge 0,$ then $f\equiv 0.$

Tags: real-analysis

I understand how we prove this corollary. Just use the Weierstrass's Theorem, we have $$\int_0^1 f(x)p(x) dx= 0 $$ and $p_n \to f$, so we have $f^2(x)=0$. Then proved.

Just I don't understand that where does $x^n$ go. Maybe I have some problem on the concept of polynomials. Why can we just replace $x^n$ with $p(x)$ here?

Comment: Is it $n>0$ or $n\ge 0$?

Comment: @zhw. you are right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $p(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k x^k$ and use the linearity of $\int$.

Comment: Should it be noted as $p_n$ as the sequence of the polynomials?

Comment: I explain why one can replace $x^n$ with $p$.